# How do i create a Document class having geopoint property in motorengine

Tags: mongodb, motorengine

Motorengine is a great library for doing async db operation with mongodb. But i am wondering how can i do a geo spacial query with motorengine.
Since the library doesn't have support for geo fields. Option i have is using motor 2dspear index. But it would be really nice if i find a way with the help of motorengine.

Can anyone please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem like this.

```
from motorengine.document import Document
import pymongo


class BaseDocument(Document):
      import pymongo

      ASCENDING = pymongo.ASCENDING
      DESCENDING = pymongo.DESCENDING
      GEO2D = pymongo.GEOSPHERE

      def __init__(self, alias=None, **kwargs):
            indexes = self.__indexes__ if hasattr(self, "__indexes__") else []
            if len(indexes) == 0:
               return

            def ensure_index(index, **spec):
               self.objects.coll(alias).ensure_index(index, **spec)

            for index_spec in indexes:
               ensure_index([index_spec])

            super(BaseDocument, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

and the using index with it.

```
class Team(BaseDocument):

     __indexes__ = [('location', BaseDocument.GEO2D)]

     name = StringField(required=True)
     location = GeoPointField()
     contact = StringField(required=True)
```